# how to send retorofit in arrayList?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

i want sending arrayList to server
but get this error log

I searched and tried the method of "openDayList[]" in filed name, but it did not work.
And the list is not serialized, so I changed it to an list because I was told to use an arrayList.

Other list() types go well, but that error comes from openDay type using pojo data class

I checked with postman that it is not a server-side problem

ex)openDay[0].a, openDay[0].b

how to fix?

log

```
{"timestamp":1690359371950,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","errors":[{"codes":["typeMismatch.shopUpdateReqParam.openDayList","typeMismatch.openDayList","typeMismatch.java.util.List","typeMismatch"],"arguments":[{"codes":["shopUpdateReqParam.openDayList","openDayList"],"arguments":null,"defaultMessage":"openDayList","code":"openDayList"}],"defaultMessage":"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'openDayList'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type ' .reqParam.ShopOpenReqParam' for property 'openDayList[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found","objectName":"shopUpdateReqParam","field":"openDayList","rejectedValue":"OpenDayList(day=MON, isOff=false, openingTime=00, closingTime=0900, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=),OpenDayList(day=TUE, isOff=false, openingTime=0930, closingTime=2100, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=),OpenDayList(day=WED, isOff=false, openingTime=, closingTime=, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=),OpenDayList(day=THU, isOff=false, openingTime=, closingTime=, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=),OpenDayList(day=FRI, isOff=false, openingTime=, closingTime=, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=),OpenDayList(day=SAT, isOff=false, openingTime=, closingTime=, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=),OpenDayList(day=SUN, isOff=false, openingTime=, closingTime=, breakTimeStart=, breakTimeOver=)","bindingFailure":true,"code":"typeMismatch"} Error count: 2","path":" "}
```

retrofit sending service

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @PATCH(" ")
    fun updateAdShop(
        @Header("X-AUTH-TOKEN") token: String,
        @Path("shopId") shopId: Long?,
        @Field("name") name: String?,
        @Field("openDayList") openDayList: ArrayList<OpenDayList>?,
    ) : Single<AdvertisingResponse>
```

Comment: my suggestion you use to JSONArray

Comment: ArrayList<OpenDayList> opendaylist=new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: JSONArray opendaylistURL = new JSONArray(opendaylist);

Comment: JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

Comment: jsonobject.put("openDayList", opendaylistURL);

Comment: URL updateAdShop = null;
updateAdShop = new URL(YOURURL + "");

Comment: JsonObjectRequest volleyJsonReques = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method. PATCH,
                        updateAdShop.toString(), jsonobject, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    }
                }

Comment: , new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                         }
                         }) {

Comment: @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        return headers; }
                };

Comment: suresh madaparthi// I tried what you suggested but got the same result